# How to convert proprietary audio file with 16kbit/s

Tags: audio, wav

has anyone an idea how to convert this 16kbit/s (maybe) proprietary audio file, back to a standard wave file?

The header strings only tell "PPCM_16" but I don't think it's a packed PCM.

The file format must be about 10 - 25 years old.

The file (it's a .bin format): https://ufile.io/wh6bc

Thank you!

Comment: have you tries sox? or librosa in python?

Comment: I only tried to open it with several different settings in an Audio player ( GoldWave ). The problem is, that I don't know the settings, and sox needs many parameters, which I all don't know, or is there an automatic possibility?

Comment: do you have any idea how it has been recorded?

Comment: Yes, it is converter to the .bin with that tool: http://www.dost-telecom.de/images/docs/downloads/Siemens/tools/HiPath_Audio_Converter_1.1.1.5.zip But there is no tool for converting it back.

Answer (score 0):

try on the command line:

```
sox yourfile.bin newfile.wav
```

and see how it goes

Comment: I've already tried this, sox tells me, that "bin" is not a known file format. :(